# Why id from Redux is undefined?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have Redux state:

```
import phones from "./../API/phone.json"

const initialState = {
   data: phones
};
```

I have component and it's containter componenet:

```
const Iphone = ({phones}) => {

  const filterIphone = phones.map((p, index) => 
    (<div className="model" key={index}>
      <NavLink to={'/CurrentIphone/' + phones.id}>{p.body.model}</NavLink>
    </div>
  ))

  return (
    <div>
      {filterIphone}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Iphone;
```

```
export class CurrentIphoneContainer extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <CurrentIphone {...this.props} />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    phones: state.phoneReducer.data
}) 


export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, {getPhones})(CurrentIphoneContainer))
```

**So the problem is in this string:**

```
<NavLink to={'/CurrentIphone/' + phones.id}>{p.body.model}</NavLink>
```

My id is undefined, although when I put id to 'p.body.id' It shows. (*When i use debugger id brings with props*)

Comment: `phones` is an array - did you mean to use `p.id`?

Comment: Robbie Averill yes it is an array

Comment: Oh my God, thank u man! sorry for stupid question

Comment: It makes sense that 'phones.id' does not work since 'phones' is an Array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<NavLink to={'/CurrentIphone/' + p.id}>{p.body.model}</NavLink>
```